# white-eyed boys

Tags: meaning

From [Virginibus Puerisque](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Virginibus_Puerisque) by Stevenson:

> I see women marrying indiscriminately with staring burgesses and
>   ferret-faced, **white-eyed** boys, and men dwell in contentment with noisy
>   scullions, or taking into their lives acidulous vestals.

What could this "white-eyed" mean? Timid?

I ventured on some googling, and found only rare instances, besides physiological senses. Such as "With an expression of white-eyed wonder, he saw me bounding up the road toward him."

Comment: Did you search?

Comment: @Kris: Naturally. Found only rare instances, besides physiological meanings. Such as "With an expression of *white-eyed wonder*, he saw me bounding up the road toward him."

Comment: When you ask for meaning, you need to show where you looked already and what you found. That's a prerequisite on this site.

Comment: White-eyed wonder sounds like a mistake for wide-eyed wonder. I wonder if the original could also be an error. Wide-eyed - meaning eyes opened wide in interest or shock - is relatively common. I've looked at the original text and neither white-eyed nor wide-eyed makes much sense though.

Comment: @TheMathemagician, ‘wide-eyed’ would make sense here, I’d say. The notion of a staring [i.e., showy, conspicuous] burgess contrasts quite nicely with that of a ferret-faced [i.e., unkempt, shy, blushing], wide-eyed [innocent, in awe, agape] boy—neither being, I would guess by the author’s tone, a very suitable hand to seek in marriage.

Answer (score 1):

> Condition unique to dark skinned people in which the pigment temporarily leaves the skin after receiving a punch to the eye. See also "skinny lip".

Also,

> A whiteeye is someone doesn't do any illegal drugs, and judges people that do use illegal drugs as being inferior to themselves.

Source: [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=whiteeye).

Comment: In ELU it is de rigueur to cite the source whenever you directly quote from another website.  (In this case, the answer is copied verbatim from urbandictionary's *[whiteeye](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=whiteeye)* entry.)  Please edit your answer and cite the source.

Comment: Good find, kid!

Comment: You think that Stevenson meant people of African descent?

Comment: @CopperKettle It's more likely that it was *awe-struck* that was meant rather. However, the answerer's effort needs to be appreciated.